# How to send data from HTML FORM to http server with form action?

Tags: html, post, get, request

I need to submit the entered form data to the server, after clicking the submit button.
Server shows error: 400 bad request
What form handler should a "form action" have?

https://codepen.io/kalkabekov/pen/MWbeqdB `<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="http://c1.ascsystems.kz:5000/forum/info">`

Comment: Test the api on postman first

Comment: api works fine in postman

Comment: Then check the network tab in your browser to see if your code is making the exact same request or not. 400 bad request means you are either missing some request parameters or giving improper value in one of them.

Comment: I was told that my submit form handler is strange, and its code is not visible. And  I am trying to send data to a production type server. Does the form action work only for php?
didn't find a project that sends data to the server

Comment: It looks fine to me